# Cocoa - connection:didFailWithError error codes

Tags: iphone, cocoa, error-handling

Where can I find the error codes and their meaning that connection:didFailWithError method can give ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's a full list](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40) of the currently supported error codes for `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Thank you ! What came to your mind to search there from the definition of the method that get only a NSError class ?

Comment: @Oliver - I found it a while ago while on my own quest to find where all the error codes were for NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

Can't post the full list of all the error codes here since there are new ones for iOS 5.0 and that is still under NDA. Go to Spotlight and search for NSURLError.h. Open it in Xcode and you can see the full list.

Comment: I'm not sure what prompted you to assume that he needed to know anything for iOS 5, but searching for `NSURLError.h` on your Mac will produce a long list of potential matches, especially if you have the most recent beta SDK along with others. Not sure that's incredibly helpful. :)

Comment: I was going to copy and paste the enumeration from the header file but was too lazy to prune the iOS 5 stuff, so figured telling him how to find it would be better.

Comment: The header is bound to become outdated at some point, better to refer to the documentation where the author of the code does a good job of maintaining it.